# Add to total of field from Database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, addition

I have a script that I'm using that when the user enters a code I want it to add to the total in the database, however nothing is happening.

This is my code so far:

```
$err = array();
if (isset($_POST['doSubmit4']) === true ) // Was if ($_POST['access']=='submit')
{
$code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['access-key']); // Was $data['access-key']
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `akid`,`key`,`total_access` FROM access_keys WHERE id='$_SESSION[user_id]' AND type='1'") or die (mysql_error()); 
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
// Match row found with more than 1 results  - the key exists. 
if ( $num > 0 ) {   
    list($akid,$key,$total_access) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    if ($code == $key) { 
        if(empty($err)){
            $total_access++;
            mysql_query("update access_keys set total_access='$total_access' where akid='$akid'") or die(mysql_error());
            header("Location: ./");
        }
    } else {
        $err[] = "Invalid Access Key. Please try again with correct access key.";
    }
} else {
    $err[] = "Error - Invalid Access Key. No access exists for your user ID.";
}       
}
```

I'm wanting it to add to the Total Access field each time the user enters the correct code, but it's not working.

This is my form code:

```
<form name="postAccess" id="postAccess" method="post" action="access.php">
    <input type="password" name="access-key" id="access-key" style="background-color:black;color:white;" size="40" /><br/>
    <input name="doSubmit4" type="submit" id="doSubmit4" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: "*it's not working.*" Where is the problem? If you're getting some errors then please append them by editing your question.

Comment: Obligatory: You should be using PDO instead of mysql_* functions, that code looks like it is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: This is what debugging is for. To pin down where the issue lies. You have a load of if statements there. I have a feeling the issue lies in the parent bracket (`if($_POST['access']=='submit')`) as you have no `else` statements going on beyond that point. Do some echoing in the `if` brackets and see what shows up and what doesn't. That will help pin-down your issue.

Comment: @Lion it's not incrementing the $total_access number. It's suppose to pull that number from the database and add 1 to it, but nothing is happening. But it's not throwing any errors to my page either.

Comment: @Kush I'm new to the MySQL side of PHP and not sure how to use them properly. If you could give me some links would helpful. :). Does "mysql_real_escape_string" not work?

Comment: @navnav I'm not sure how to debug PHP? I'm from an ASP.Net background and usually use Visual Studio, but I'm just learning Dreamweaver.

Comment: I suspect that the `if` condition should be something like this `if (isset($_POST['access']))`. Additionally, the *form id* and the *password field id* are same `access`.

Comment: @dpDesignz Fair enough. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be your parent if brackets.

Try:

```
if (isset($_POST['access']) === true )
```

instead of

```
if ( $_POST['access']=='submit' )
```

If that doesn't seem to do it, do some debugging.

Throw some echo statements in those if brackets to see what conditions are true and what are not.

EDIT:

I just realized another problem.

Your form action is invalid. This should be the path to the page you are posting the data to. So:

Instead of:

`<form name="access" id="access" method="post" action="access">`

You should have:

```
<form name="access" id="access" method="post" action="your-php-path-here.php">
```

**Notice how `action` = "your-php-path-here.php" in the above code.**

Comment: Ok Thanks. I chucked an error in there in an else statement under the if (isset($_POST['access']) === true ) and it definitely isn't picking up the post action. So not sure what next.

Comment: Try `$_POST['doSubmit4']` instead of `$_POST['access']`.

Comment: Just tried and that's working. :). It's getting to the loop no as far as the code, but now it's not pulling any information from the password field. I'v tried debugging to display what I right to the page but it's blank so far.

Comment: Hmm... Try doing a `print_r($_POST);` at the top of the document. Post the result here. xD

Comment: got it! `$code = mysql_real_escape_string($data['access-key']);` needs to be `$code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['access-key']);` Thanks for all your help!